# Angular 4 issue with external pictures and js

Tags: angular

I have just upgraded my project to Angular 4. It cannot find any external javascript and images. All the paths are like "app/scripts/test.js"
and it gives 404 error

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "app/scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js",
        "app/scripts/jquery.min.js",
        "app/scripts/jquery-ui.js",
        "app/scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
        "app/scripts/Chart.min.js",
        "app/scripts/toggle.js",
        "app/scripts/div.js",
        "app/scripts/functions.js",
        "app/scripts/search.js",
        "app/scripts/modal-open-close.js",
        "app/scripts/contextMenu.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Do you really think that we will be able to help you with only these information? Please give us more details.

Comment: That's it. I don't include them elsewhere like styles.css and angular-cli. It worked okay before the upgrade. The folder with the images is local

Comment: Please include what is your build system, if you are using SystemJS, WEbPack are you using Angular-cli? If yes how does your angular-cli.json files look like.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"scripts": [
    "app/scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js",
    "app/scripts/jquery.min.js",
    "app/scripts/jquery-ui.js",
    "app/scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
    "app/scripts/Chart.min.js",
    "app/scripts/toggle.js",
    "app/scripts/div.js",
    "app/scripts/functions.js",
    "app/scripts/search.js",
    "app/scripts/modal-open-close.js",
    "app/scripts/contextMenu.js"
  ],
```

to

```
"scripts": [
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
...
]
```

for every one library that you use and it is installed, if not install it via npm.